# how to store database IOS program

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm a newbie, and i'm trying to re-code a programe like this:[foodlover](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mmHBEmfBn0) . but i don't know how to store database to this application. Can some one help me?  thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is good if you want to use a database directly.  If you'd rather think in terms of objects, look at [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial helpful when I started trying to wrap my head around Core Data;

[Core Data Basics - Tim Roadley](http://timroadley.com/2012/02/09/core-data-basics-part-1-storyboards-delegation/)